# xml parsing in android, wp7, ios for audio streaming

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, audio-streaming

I am developing an application in android, wp7, ios for audio streaming.
the url is an xml file, which fetches the data for the web. after getting the data i used xmlpullparser in android to parse, but im having difficulty in streaming the audio when i click on the parsed list of data containing the song title.

any suggestions please feel free to post them.

Comment: "I am developing an application in android, wp7, ios" - what cross-platform framework are you using?

Comment: Can you describe where your difficulties are? Where precisely are you stuck?

Comment: Perhaps this might be easier to break up into individual questions, how are you supposed to mark multiple answers as the right answer should multiple individuals provide one, and the question is a little vague, have you attempted to parse XML in WP7?

Comment: > "I am developing an application in android, wp7, ios" - what
> cross-platform framework are you using? no im not using any cross platform frame work, i am using the native development for three of them. like developing the android in eclipse & wp7 in vs2010 & ios in xcode. from scratch in the three platform

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP Live Stream for iOS:

```
https://developer.apple.com/streaming/
```

MediaPlayer for Android:

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html
```

and Audio Streaming Agent for Windows Phone 8

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
```